# Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 4654636' returns error 'UNSUPPORTED''

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, run-app

I just updated my Android Studio to version 3.5. When I run App using my phone, it successfully compiles, but an error occurs during the installation process.

Error :

> Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4.
>   Installation did not succeed.
>   The application could not be installed.
>   Installation failed due to:''pm install-create -r -t -S 4654636' returns error 'UNSUPPORTED'

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by disabling MIUI optimization from developed options:
      **Settings - Developer options - MIUI optimization**
  **Disable** it and it will ask to **reboot** the device, after that the app can be installed

Comment: for me didn't help for mi-4c